# Exploding multiple array columns in spark for a changing input schema in PySpark

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have the same situation as stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539078/exploding-multiple-array-columns-in-spark-for-a-changing-input-schema).

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, "xx", [10, 20], ["a", "b"], ["p", "q"]),
     (2, "yy", [30, 40], ["c", "d"], ["r", "s"]),
     (3, "zz",     None, ["f", "g"], ["e", "k"])],
    ["c1", "c2", "a1", "a2", "a3"])
df.show()
# +---+---+--------+------+------+
# | c1| c2|      a1|    a2|    a3|
# +---+---+--------+------+------+
# |  1| xx|[10, 20]|[a, b]|[p, q]|
# |  2| yy|[30, 40]|[c, d]|[r, s]|
# |  3| zz|    null|[f, g]|[e, k]|
# +---+---+--------+------+------+
```

I can't figure out a way to explode it correctly in PySpark. How I can achieve this result?

```
+---+---+----+---+---+
| c1| c2|  a1| a2| a3|
+---+---+----+---+---+
|  1| xx|  10|  a|  p|
|  1| xx|  20|  b|  q|
|  2| yy|  30|  c|  r|
|  2| yy|  40|  d|  s|
|  3| zz|null|  f|  e|
|  3| zz|null|  g|  k|
+---+---+----+---+---+
```

Comment: The post has a working solution as confirmed by the user who raised the question. Did you try the solution? With little efforts you should be able convert the scala code from that post to pyspark.

Comment: @AzharKhan - the accepted answer is not simple to translate for someone who is not familiar with Scala. Now I know some Scala, but that answer would still require quite much of searching what that syntax means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do it for dynamic number of array columns.

Spark 3:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

arr_cols = [c[0] for c in df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == "array"]
df = df.withColumn(
    "arr_of_struct",
    F.arrays_zip(*[F.coalesce(c, F.array(F.lit(None))).alias(c) for c in arr_cols])
).select(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c not in arr_cols],
    F.expr("inline(arr_of_struct)")
)

df.show()
# +---+---+----+---+---+
# | c1| c2|  a1| a2| a3|
# +---+---+----+---+---+
# |  1| xx|  10|  a|  p|
# |  1| xx|  20|  b|  q|
# |  2| yy|  30|  c|  r|
# |  2| yy|  40|  d|  s|
# |  3| zz|null|  f|  e|
# |  3| zz|null|  g|  k|
# +---+---+----+---+---+
```

Spark 2:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

arr_cols = [c[0] for c in df.dtypes if c[1][:5] == "array"]
df = df.withColumn(
    "my_struct",
    F.explode(F.arrays_zip(*[F.coalesce(c, F.array(F.lit(None))) for c in arr_cols]))
).select(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c not in arr_cols],
    *[F.col(f"my_struct.{i}").alias(c) for i, c in enumerate(arr_cols)]
)
```

Comment: @Quynh-MaiChu if you have a list of columns to explode, you can first create a new column with the `arrays_zip` and then use it in `inline`. `withColumn('arr_of_structs', func.arrays_zip(*column_list)).selectExpr('c1', 'c2', 'inline(arr_of_structs)')`

Comment: Thank you, very helpful for someone who has little knowledge in pyspark :)